# Browser scrollbars for a flash website

Tags: apache-flex, flash

I've made a page entirely in flash (flex actionscript project), and for weird reasons, should'nt scale when opened with a small windowed browser (low resolution or not maximized); in this case I need to have to browser scrollbar active to show the full flash application.

How can that be done?

Note: I don't want to implement a scroll method in flash (like flash scrollbars, or a mouse position related scroller), i just want to summon the browser scrollbars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just embed the flash with a fixed (not proportional) size. If it is larger than the browser window, the scrollbars will appear.

Also make sure that the html element containing the swf is either big enough to show the entire flash or doesn't have it's `overflow` css property set to `hidden`.

Answer (score 1):

To show the scrollbars you can try this.

```
html {
     overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
     overflow: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE

StageAlign.TOP_LEFT

?
maybe it should happen from within the SWF..

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you looking for : http://swffit.millermedeiros.com/

> swffit automatically resizes your
>   flash to 100% width and 100% height
>   (full bleed) when your browser window
>   is greater than the minimum desired
>   size and resizes flash to the minimum
>   desired size when the browser window
>   is smaller... It can also resize the
>   flash movie to a maximum size if the
>   browser window size is greater than
>   the maximum size...